# remove at index linked list

Tags: java, list

Hi im trying to remove a link in part of a linked list but i'm not sure how to remove the link. when i run it the links are still there. im using a junit to test the function if that matters .

Here is what i have so far.

```
public void removeAt(int k)
{
   Node w = first;
   int counter = 0; 
   if (k<0 ||  k >= size())
   {
       throw new  IndexOutOfBoundsException("Error ");
   }
   else 
   {
       while (w!= null)
       {
         counter++; 
         if (counter == k)
         {
            Node now = w.next; 
            w= now.next; 
         } 
         w=w.next;
       }
   }
   assert check();
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is your actual task? Is it to remove an element from the linked list?

Comment: yes i am trying to remove a element from the link but every time i check it is the same

Comment: I think you need to make sure that you understand what a `linked list` actually is.  What keeps it linked together.  When you know it your task will be to take one element out of the list while maintaining the linked status of all the remaining elements.  It's like you will need to remove just one car from a train.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change a node's `.next` field in order to remove a node, e.g. `w.next = w.next.next` removes the `w.next` node from the list (because nothing is pointing to it anymore); be sure to check for null pointers (if `w.next` is null then `w.next.next` will throw an exception).  Also, add a `break` statement to the end of your if block since there's no need to traverse the rest of the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (counter == k){
    Node now = w.next; 
    w.next= now.next; 
    break;
}
```

test this.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating a local variable.  What you need to do is update the link prior to the current node:

```
 if (k == 0)
    {
      first = first.next ;
      // you also have to free the memory for first.
    }
    else 
    {  
     Node Last = first ;
     w = first.next ;
     counter = 1 ;
     while (w!= null)
     {
       counter++; // Not sure your conventions, but I think this should be at the end
        if (counter == k)
        {
          last.next = w.next ; /// happily skipping w :)
          // remember you have to free w
          break ; // no point in continuing to the end.

        } 
       w=w.next;
     }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You always need to keep track of the previous node. And also what if the node that's to be deleted is the first node? I guess you need to change the while block to look something like:

```
Node l = first;
while (w!= null)
{
    if (counter == k)
    {
        if (w == first)
            first = w.next;
        else    
            l.next = w.next;            
        w.next = null;                  
        break;  
    } 
    l=w;
    w=w.next;
    counter++; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code that remove the element from linked list,

```
public void delete(T element){

        if(head != null){  // first check your header node is null or not

            // create two references of your linked list 
            Node<T> tmp = head;    // it will hold current value 
            Node<T> tmp1 = head.getNextRef(); // it will hold next value


            while(true){ // iterate through whole linked list

                if(head.getValue() == element){  // if you found element at first place 
                    head = head.getNextRef();   // then point head to next node of it
                    break;
                }

                if(tmp1.getValue()==element){  // to remove node refer to next of tmp1
                    tmp.setNextRef(tmp1.getNextRef());
                    break;   
                }else{
                    tmp = tmp1;  
                    tmp1 = tmp1.getNextRef();

                    if(tmp1==null)
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```